# How to get AppEngine map reduce to scale out?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-cloud-storage

I have written a simple MapReduce flow to read in lines from a CSV from a file on Google Cloud Storage and subsequently make an Entity.  However, **I can't seem to get it to run on more than one shard**.

The code makes use of mapreduce.control.start_map and looks something like this.

```
class LoadEntitiesPipeline(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        id = control.start_map(map_name,
                          handler_spec="backend.line_processor",
                          reader_spec="mapreduce.input_readers.FileInputReader",
                          queue_name=get_queue_name("q-1"),
                          shard_count=shard_count,
                          mapper_parameters={
                              'shard_count': shard_count,
                              'batch_size': 50,
                              'processing_rate': 1000000,
                              'files': [gsfile],
                              'format': 'lines'})
```

I have shard_count in both places, because I'm not sure what methods actually need it.  Setting shard_count anywhere from 8 to 32, doesn't change anything as the status page always says 1/1 shards running. To separate things, I've made everything run on a backend queue with a large number of instances.  I've tried adjusting the queue parameters [per this wiki](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/InstancesQueuesShardsAndSlices).  In the end, it seems to just run serially.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Update (Still no success):**

In trying to isolate things, I tried making the call using direct calls to pipeline like so:

```
class ImportHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, gsfile):
        pipeline = LoadEntitiesPipeline2(gsfile)
        pipeline.start(queue_name=get_queue_name("q-1"))

        self.redirect(pipeline.base_path + "/status?root=" + pipeline.pipeline_id)


class LoadEntitiesPipeline2(base_handler.PipelineBase):

    def run(self, gsfile):
        yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapperPipeline(
           'loadentities2_' + gsfile,
           'backend.line_processor',
           'mapreduce.input_readers.FileInputReader',
           params={'files': [gsfile], 'format': 'lines'},
           shards=32
        )
```

With this new code, it still only runs on one shard.  **I'm starting to wonder if mapreduce.input_readers.FileInputReader is capable of parallelizing input by line.**

Answer (score 5):

It looks like `FileInputReader` can only shard via files. The `format` params only change the way mapper function got call. If you pass more than one files to the mapper, it will start to run on more than one shard. Otherwise it will only use one shard to process the data.

## EDIT #1:

After dig deeper in the mapreduce library. MapReduce will decide whether or not to split file into pieces based on the `can_split` method return for each file type it defined. Currently, the only format which implement `split` method is `ZipFormat`. So, if your file format is not zip, it won't split the file to run on more than one shard.

```
@classmethod
  def can_split(cls):
    """Indicates whether this format support splitting within a file boundary.

    Returns:
      True if a FileFormat allows its inputs to be splitted into
    different shards.
    """
```

https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/python/src/mapreduce/file_formats.py

But it looks like it is possible to write your own file format split method. You can try to hack and add `split` method on `_TextFormat` first and see if more than one shard running.

```
@classmethod
def split(cls, desired_size, start_index, opened_file, cache):
    pass
```

## EDIT #2:

An easy workaround would be left the `FileInputReader` run serially but move the time-cosuming task to  parallel `reduce` stage.

```
def line_processor(line):
    # serial
    yield (random.randrange(1000), line)

def reducer(key, values):
    # parallel
    entities = []
    for v in values:
        entities.append(CREATE_ENTITY_FROM_VALUE(v))
    db.put(entities)
```

## EDIT #3:

If try to modify the `FileFormat`, here is an example (haven't been test yet)

```
from file_formats import _TextFormat, FORMATS


class _LinesSplitFormat(_TextFormat):
  """Read file line by line."""

  NAME = 'split_lines'

  def get_next(self):
    """Inherited."""
    index = self.get_index()
    cache = self.get_cache()
    offset = sum(cache['infolist'][:index])

    self.get_current_file.seek(offset)
    result = self.get_current_file().readline()
    if not result:
      raise EOFError()
    if 'encoding' in self._kwargs:
      result = result.encode(self._kwargs['encoding'])
    return result

  @classmethod
  def can_split(cls):
    """Inherited."""
    return True

  @classmethod
  def split(cls, desired_size, start_index, opened_file, cache):
    """Inherited."""
    if 'infolist' in cache:
      infolist = cache['infolist']
    else:
      infolist = []
      for i in opened_file:
        infolist.append(len(i))
        cache['infolist'] = infolist

    index = start_index
    while desired_size > 0 and index < len(infolist):
      desired_size -= infolist[index]
      index += 1
    return desired_size, index


FORMATS['split_lines'] = _LinesSplitFormat
```

Then the new file format can be called via change the mapper_parameters from `lines` to `split_line`.

```
class LoadEntitiesPipeline(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    id = control.start_map(map_name,
                      handler_spec="backend.line_processor",
                      reader_spec="mapreduce.input_readers.FileInputReader",
                      queue_name=get_queue_name("q-1"),
                      shard_count=shard_count,
                      mapper_parameters={
                          'shard_count': shard_count,
                          'batch_size': 50,
                          'processing_rate': 1000000,
                          'files': [gsfile],
                          'format': 'split_lines'})
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer, and the suggested workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like FileInputReader should be capable of sharding based on a quick reading of:
https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/python/src/mapreduce/input_readers.py

It looks like 'format': 'lines' should split using: self.get_current_file().readline()

Does it seem to be interpreting the lines correctly when it is working serially? Maybe the line breaks are the wrong encoding or something.

Comment: Yeah, there is nothing strange with my newline encoding, and it is able to process each line fine, just no sharding at line granularity. In fact, when I split the really large file into smaller files (say 5000 lines each).  I get can get the mapreduce call to shard, but it looks like it is sharding by filenames and not at any finer granularity.

Answer (score 0):

From experience FileInputReader will do a max of one shard per file. 
Solution: Split your big files. I use split_file in https://github.com/johnwlockwood/karl_data to shard files before uploading them to Cloud Storage.
If the big files are already up there, you can use a Compute Engine instance to pull them down and do the sharding because the transfer speed will be fastest.
FYI: karld is in the cheeseshop so you can `pip install karld`